# WhiteRaccoon How do I use it?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have just downloaded WhiteRaccoon for the iOS platform. I put it in my project classes folder, and imported it into one of my classes.

I compiled it just to check everything was ok before I started, and it had 4 errors:

```
"_CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL", referenced from:

"_kCFFTPResourceName", referenced from:

"_CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL", referenced from:

"_CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing", referenced from:
```

Please help!

By the way: the reason why I’m using WhiteRaccoon is because no one else has made any tutorials that actually make sense with FTP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need to link the CFNetwork framework.

I determined that by Googling your first error message verbatim, which is a good habit to get into.

Error message you don't understand? Google it.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem. Now there is another problem. All the right credentials have been entered in the login code. And it does not seem to download the files.. It NSLogs out a message of it succeeds with a connection. Why is this? It works with Filezilla and web browsers. -(void) requestFailed:(WRRequest *) request{
 //called after 'request' ends in error
 //we can print the error message
 NSLog(@"%@", request.error.message);
} Is the part thats supposed to work. But it does not show any signs of been executed.

Comment: Please ask a separate question for this so it can be searched for and have its own answers...